# How to pass list of names to be searched by grep using xargs?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, xargs

I have a text file containing names (`nameslist.txt`) and I want to read them using `cat` and pipe the result with `xargs` to a `grep` command, so that `grep` checks the existence of each name that it receives in a target file (`targetfile.txt`).

Let's say `targetfile.txt` contains a large number of names which might have some of those names in `nameslist.txt`.

What should I add between `xargs` and `grep`, and between `grep` and `./targetfile.txt`, below?

```
cat ./nameslist.txt | xargs grep ./targetfile.txt
```

Thank you

Comment: Assuming one name per line, you don't need `xargs` here - `grep` can read a list of patterns (or fixed strings, with the `-F` option) from a file: `grep -F -f nameslist.txt ./targetfile.txt`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `-I` to tell `xargs` to use a particular character or sequence of characters as a placeholder for the argument. From `man xargs`:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
          names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
          terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
          character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

A common choice is `{}` so

```
cat nameslist.txt | xargs -I {} grep {} targetfile.txt
```

or (without the useless use of cat)

```
< nameslist.txt xargs -I {} grep {} targetfile.txt
```

However, assuming your list has one name per line you don't need `xargs` here at all - `grep` can read a list of patterns (or fixed strings, with the `-F` option) from a file:

```
grep -F -f nameslist.txt targetfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 100% what I was looking for. Pretty informative.